# Mod_rewrite for a dynamic url below

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I'm afraid its very complicated for me, so just wondered if anyone can help me out by showing me the code to achieve the following result?

I have a dynamic url of:
www.mydomain.com/art.php?artist=Philip%20Hughes&title=The%20Blue%20Swan%20Lake%20on%20the%20water

and would like to show the above url as:

www.mydomain.com/art/philip-hughes/the-blue-swan-lake-on-the-water

with hyphens between spaces and all lower case? Is this possible? I don't know if it is, as I've been looking for weeks now.

Thanks
Mark

Comment: You should be able to do this by a simple URL rewrite, look at http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: If your data comes from database, you are likely to run into problems if the names or titles can contain `-` characters; you will not be able to easily look up information based on the edited names / titles.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for replying. I'm a bit further on for both your comments, cheers